# Is the pressure inside a closed refrigerator same as atmospheric pressure?

Tags: pressure, temperature, freezing

What is the pressure in my deep refrigerator where water becomes ice. Is it lower than atmospheric pressure or higher or same? And how I can mesure it ?

Comment: Maybe use a weather board with sensors which measure humidity, temperature and pressure. For instance, I would use something like https://wiki.odroid.com/accessory/sensor/weather-board/weather-board running on Odroid-C2 since Odroid-C2 will run on 5V lithium ion battery for almost 8 hours. Log the data to the computer. Maybe put it in a plastic bag to keep it dry.

Comment: A __modern frost free refrigerator__ usually has a drain tube that will allow the pressure to equalise.  A __decent freezer__ usually has better seals and no defrost drain and after filling with warm room air will achieve reduced pressure as the air is cooled after closing the door/lid before small leaks allow the pressure to equalise.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to be either *slightly* lower than atmospheric pressure, or the same as atmospheric pressure.

It wouldn't make much sense to have a fridge at a higher pressure than the surroundings as far as I can tell.  It would require energy to maintain that temperature, it would be harder to keep the door closed, and it might cause things to freeze at a higher temperature, which rarely seems desirable, since regular pressure would undo that freezing anyways.

After long operations, I would expect the pressure in the freezer to be near atmospheric pressure.  If the pressure were much lower, it could make it very difficult to open the freezer, and it would also have a tendency to draw in the surrounding warm air through any cracks to try to equalize the pressures.

If the fridge were recently opened, you might expect temporarily lower pressure in the fridge, because you brought in room temperature air at atmospheric pressure, and when that begins to cool to the surroundings it compresses, and would lower the pressure in the fridge until more cold air is pumped in.  It's worth noting that when I saw the pressure is lower here, I don't mean by a significant amount.  Just considering the size of refrigerator doors, it should be pretty apparent that a slight pressure difference would require substantial force to act against; but you can notice that it is *slightly* harder to open fridge doors if they have recently been opened.

If you want to measure for yourself, I'm sure you could find some sort of barometer to measure the temperature.  You might want one that records data, so that you can measure while the fridge is closed instead of having to open the fridge and hope the pressure doesn't change too much (because obviously opening the fridge will change the pressure).

Comment: "…but you can notice that it is *slightly* harder to open fridge doors if they have recently been opened." Only if they are designed to be properly inefficient. It is quite common to find that you have to give quite a vicious yank if you want to reopen a fridge or freezer door immediately after closing it. I have also seen complaints online about certain brands of freezer being so inappropriately well sealed that when you closed them you had no way of getting back in for several minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The pressure inside the fridge will be atmospheric as the seals around the door are not perfect. They are only there to minimize the air entering / escaping when the door is shut to help the efficiency.

If you want to try, you could make a perfectly sealing door and reduce the pressure compared to atmospheric by 1lb/sq in and see how easy it is to open the door. Think of an unopened jam jar and how difficult they can be to open...

Comment: I agree.  I expect a slight vacuum in the refrigerator, but "perfect" seals would lower the inside pressure enough (via the ideal gas law) that it would be very difficult to open the refrigerator door.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the refrigerant is.

Maybe it uses R134a, tetrafluorethane, C$_2$H$_2$F$_4$. Boiling point at atmospheric pressure is −26,3 °C. The high pressure side should be in the range of 8 to 12 atm.

But I may have misunderstood the question. If you want to know the pressure in the fridge, use a mobile phone with a pressure sensor and a data logger app.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the pressure inside...

Answered.  (But yes -- atmospheric, because, leaky seals).

> How can I measure it?

One of two ways:

- Cheap and invasive: drill a hole through your deep freezer wall, and install a mechanical vacuum gauge (or an absolute pressure gauge).
- Expensive but your housemates will allow you to live: get or make a datalogger & connected it to an electronic absolute pressure gauge.  Chuck it in the freezer for a bit, then take it out and see what it says.
- Somewhere in the middle: find an electronic absolute pressure gauge that you can read with a voltmeter, or some other direct connection.  Connect it to some FFC cable (because FFC cable is thin enough that you can close the freezer on it).  Hang it in the freezer, turn on the meter, close the door, observe the voltage.

Answer (score -3):

if  tightly closed while water becomes ice, the pressure inside will be higher than outside, because ice take more space than water.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me to assume that he would be talking about a fridge _full_ of ice.  Typically they need some sort of airflow to actually operate AFAIK.